# Using c++ to decode qr code from a png to a link

Tags: c++, qr-code, zxing

I am currently in the process of learn c++ and I have decided to make a simple program that takes a .png file and exports the link inside it. I have looked it up and discovered ZXing but I still can't figure out how to implement it easily.

The ones I've found consists of scanning using webcam etc instead of a very simple version.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a library to read the images. CImg is good, it is a header only library build on top of the base libraries for the different images format: https://cimg.eu/

Assuming the image is a clean QR code you can skip the complex computer vision recognition part.

For the decoding part I am not sure, I don't know ZXing but it looks like the c++ port is no longer maintained anyway. Still, once you have the clean image it should not be a problem to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the most recent c++ port of ZXing: https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp

The project includes a trivial example application that does exactly what you want.